# Postgres generate a unique username

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a requirement where I need to generate to unique usernames. I know how I would do it server side but want to make it as efficient as possible and do it on the database as part of a procedure but unsure where to start as I don't work with SQL too often.

I want to be able to create a username using the first letter of their forename and their surname plus some numbers and if a user already exists with that username then update it by 1. e.g.

I have users

- Bob Jones bjones1
- Bill Jones bjones2

If a user Beatrice Jones is added then that will be bjones3.

However users can choose to pick their username  so someone may have already chosen bjones3 so I want it to automatically generate bjones4.

If there are no user B Jones then the first username created should be bjones

Ideally this would all happen as part of the user insert into the database so my Go code just executes a single database call and the user gets inserted.

Update:

When a user chooses their own username I check if it exists and block them from using it if it exists.

Comment: To clarify, if bjones doesn't exist, would the username created be bjones00001 or bjones?

Comment: _However users can choose to pick their username_: Hopefully no one picks `user1` as its username

Comment: I suppose it would make more sense to be bjones

Comment: The number the user has selected could affect a few things when you are expecting a text + fixed size number pattern

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I think this will do:

```
select 'bjones' || coalesce(lpad( ((regexp_match(max(username), '[0-9]+$'))[1]::int + 1)::text, 5, '0'), '00000')
from t
where username ~ '^bjones[0-9]{5}$';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f29db01cb214be727792a70b42bf5a39) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Shouldn't the search also be using a regex expression, to prevent the existing user `billy joneskt (bjoneskt1234)` from affecting the ID?

Comment: Good call, JGH.It does not work correctly unless you do so. Yet there is a drawback - regexp search will defeat `username` index if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

More strict and parameterized, with 4-digit sequential number.

```
with 
unp as -- user name prefix
(select left(lower(:givenname), 1) || lower(:surname) unp),
maxno as -- max existing seq.number for this username prefix
(
    select coalesce(max((regexp_match(username, '(\d+)$'))[1]::integer), 0) maxno 
    from usernames
    where username ~ ('^'||(select unp from unp)||'\d+$')
)   
select (select unp from unp) || to_char((select maxno + 1 from maxno), 'FM0009')  username;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with the following code:

```
_username = left(lower(_firstname), 1) || lower(_lastname);
PERFORM id FROM users WHERE username = _username;
IF FOUND THEN
  FOR i in 1 .. 999
  LOOP
    _username := _username || i;
    PERFORM id FROM users WHERE username = _username;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END IF;
```